# NP-hardness of problem with indices and subsets

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

Consider the following problem.

> Let $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and $A_{ij}\subseteq S$ for $i,j\in S$. Does there exist a *strict* subset $T\subset S$ such that for all $j\not\in T$, there exists $i\in T$ for which $T\subseteq A_{ij}$?

(For $T=S$, this is trivially true, so we disallow it.)

The problem is in NP: given a set $T$, it is easy to verify whether it satisfies the property. Is it also NP-complete, or does there exist a polytime algorithm?

I thought about reducing from SAT. So we start with constraints like $$(x_1\vee \neg x_2\vee x_4)\wedge(\neg x_3\vee \neg x_4)\wedge\dots.$$ Each $x_i$ can refer to $i\in T$. So we want to express statements like

$$(1\in T\vee 2\not\in T\vee 4\in T)\wedge(3\not\in T\vee 4\not\in T)\wedge\dots$$

How can we do this?

Comment: I think the question is ill posed or has trivially no solution. If $T$ is $A_{ij}$, it must necessarily contain $j$. But by definition $j$ is not in $T$. So the question does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

It will be less confusing if we allow ourselves to label the elements of $S$ by something else than natural numbers, so let's instead take
$$ S=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k,x_1,\bar x_1,x_1,\bar x_2,\ldots,x_n,\bar x_n\} $$
with one element per clause in your SAT problem and *two* elements for each variable -- one will be set if the variable is true, the other if the variable is false. Splitting a variable in two like this is very common trick for reducing from SAT.

The elements $c_k$ will be in none of the $A_{ij}$s. Since by specification there must be *some* element missing from $T$, this will force all of the $c_i$s be absent from $T$.

Can you select values for $A_{ix_j}$ and $A_{i\bar x_j}$ that force $T$ to contain exactly one of $x_j$ and $\bar x_j$, and values for $A_{ic_j}$ that enforce each of the clauses in your incoming SAT problem?

Comment: To ensure that at least one of $x_j,\bar{x_j}$ must be selected, I think we can select $\bar{x_j}\in A_{x_j\bar{x_j}}$ and $i\not\in A_{i\bar{x_j}}$ otherwise and similarly $x_j\in A_{\bar{x_j}x_j}$ and $i\not\in A_{ix_j}$ otherwise. I'm not sure how to ensure that at most one must be selected, though.

Comment: @user355066: One strategy would be to make sure that $x_i\notin A_{\bar x_i j}$ for any $j$. This doesn't _force_ one of $x_i$ or $\bar x_i$ to be absent, but does guarantee that _if_ both are present in $T$, one can safely be removed without sacrificing the validity of $T$.